# Does jQuery fadeOut() effect SEO on heading tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, seo

I have some code to fade out a h1 tag after 6 seconds as some other content replaces it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("h1.heading-text").fadeTo(1500, 0, function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
}, 6000);
```

Would SEO be effected because the heading tag gets hidden on the page?

I'm guessing not because crawlers don't often run JS.

Thanks.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript/63451#63451

Comment: `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` will be ignored by most screen readers (including crawlers). You can try position the element offscreen by a class like: `.hidden 
{position:absolute;
left:-10000px;
top:auto;
width:1px;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;}`